# Replacing single character or multiples of character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace newline `\n`. If there is one occurrence it gets replaced with `<br>`. If there are two or more in a row it gets replaced with `<br><br>`. I can do either or but I am not sure how to do both for the same variable.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague and you've provided us no code to examine. Are you trying to do this replacing on rows from a mysql query?

Comment: @Norse There isn't anything else to it. If there is a variable that has `\n` that gets replaced with `<br>`. If it has `\n\n`, `\n\n\n`, etc that gets replaced with `<br><br>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace two or more with the same number of line breaks, str_replace should work.

```
str_replace("\n", '<br />', $text);
```

If however, you want to replace three newline characters with only two line breaks then you'll have to perform two replaces, at least one using a regular expression:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "<br /><br />", $text);
$text = str_replace("\n", '<br />', $text);
```

Comment: This will work but he's also asking how to replace more than two line breaks as well.

Comment: {2,} means two or more. The first example replaces all '\n' with '<br />', the second example replaces all occurrences of '\n' which occur twice or more in a row with '<br /><br />' then performs the first step of replacing single occurrences.

Comment: Second part is what I was looking for. I forogt about being able to use `{x,y}`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$pattern = array("/\n\n+/", "/\n/");
$replacement = array('<br/><br/>',  '<br/>' );
$str = "The quick \nbrown fox \n\n\njumps over \n\nthe lazy dog.";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Just replace <br/> with <br> if <br> is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

As a (hopefully simpler) variant of Godwin's solution, try:

```
$text = str_replace("\n\n", '<br /><br />', $text);
$text = str_replace("\n", '<br />', $text);
```

This will replace any 2 successive newlines with 2 line breaks, then if there are any single newlines remaining, they will be replaced by single line breaks. This would implement your substitutions for 1, 2, or 3 (or more) successive newlines.

Comment: This would replace three successive newline characters with three linebreaks, however @qitch was wanting a solution that replaces three newlines with only two linebreaks.